# How do I merge latitude and longitude as an input?

Tags: r, svm, prediction, r-caret, feature-selection

My paper topic is house price prediction with Support Vector Regression.
First, I want to select feature.
So I use package `caret` to do feature selection.
But I have a question, my data frame have latitude and longitude.
How do I made latitude and longitude as an input?
This is my a part data frame:

```
      estate_Lat  estate_Lon  estate_TotolPrice
[1, ] 25.02862    121.5059    124117
[2, ] 25.03377    121.5089    2568347
[3, ] 25.04346    121.512     73000000
[4, ] 25.04348    121.512     5600000
[5, ] 25.04346    121.512     99300000
```

Complete file in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3yajiotvdn9jxb/TestDatasetR_1000.xlsx?dl=0).

And this is my code:

```
#set.seed(7)
ibrary(mlbench)
library(caret)
mydata <- read.csv("D:/SupportVectorRegression/Origin/TestDatasetR_1000.csv", header=TRUE)
#location <- data.matrix(mydata[, c("estate_Lng", "estate_Lat")])
#location <- as.factor(paste(mydata[, c("estate_Lng", "estate_Lat")]))
#test <- as.factor(paste(mydata$estate_Lng, mydata$estate_Lat))
mydata$meuse.xy <- data.frame(mydata[, c("estate_Lng", "estate_Lat")])
estate_TotalPrice <- mydata$estate_TotalPrice
rfectrl <- rfeControl(functions=lmFuncs, method="cv", number=10, repeats=3,verbose=TRUE,returnResamp = "final")
results <- rfe(mydata$meuse.xy, estate_TotalPrice,sizes=c(1:2),rfeControl=rfectrl,method = "svmRadial",metric = "Rsquared")
print(results)
predictors(results)
plot(results, type=c("g", "o"))
```

I want to show the results：

```
> predictors(results)
 [1] "estate_HouseArea"      "estate_LandArea"       "estate_Price"          "estate_ParkingLot"     "estate_ZoneUse"       
 [6] "estate_TransFloor"     "estate_Land"           "estate_HouseRoom_1"    "estate_TotalFloor"     "estate_HouseRoom_4"   
[11] "estate_ParkingType"    "River_Distance"        "estate_ParkingPrice"   "estate_House"          "THSR_StationDistance" 
[16] "estate_TransType"      "Lib_Distance"          "estate_HouseMaterials" ***"estate_Lat"            "estate_Lng"***           
[21] "ParkS_Distance"        "Hosp_Distance"         "estate_HouseRoom_3"    "Post_Distance"         "Hyper_Distance"       
[26] "estate_HouseType"      "estate_HouseDate"      "estate_HouseUse"
```

However, latitude and longitude are separated. I hope latitude and longitude they can merge, then called location.
What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Is your question how to do it from a statistical perspective, or how do you implement the code to include latitude and longitude?

Comment: Yes, is statistical perspective.

Comment: I try to write this.→ latlon <- data.matrix(mydata[, c("estate_Lng", "estate_Lat")])
location<-SpatialPoints(latlon)

rfectrl <- rfeControl(functions=lmFuncs, method="cv", number=10, repeats=3,verbose=TRUE,returnResamp = "final")
results <- rfe(location@coords, mydata$estate_TotalPrice,sizes = c(1:45),rfeControl=rfectrl,method = "svmRadial",metric = "RMSE")
#metric = "Rsquared"

print(results)
predictors(results)
plot(results, type=c("g", "o"))

Comment: do you want to do feature elimination and make sure (latitude, longitude) are treated as one feature i.e. ranked and eliminated together instead of individually ?

Answer (score 0):

Latitude and Longitude are the coordinates on a sphere that provide the position of "location". From a quick look at some of your other attributes which include the word "distance" within them then you will need to use an R library that understands latitude, longitude and distance to precalculate the desired features prior to running your other functions.